# OS pop-up in Jmeter selenium webdriver to attach a file?

Tags: jmeter

I have to automate a workflow which talks about attaching a file using JMeter selenium Webdriver. Not able to deal with the OS pop-up. Can somebody provide me the solution specific to JMeter Selenium Webdriver?

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as:

```
WDS.browser.findElement(org.openqa.selenium.By.id('file-input-id')).sendKeys('/full/path/to/file/to/upload')
```

Also it worth seeing [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-10-questions-answered) guide for how-to's on the most frequently asked questions on the WebDriver Sampler.

Comment: No it's not as while I click on fileupload button it opens a new OS pop up where i have to browse a file ( or provide a file path) and as it's(pop up window) not part of browser JMeter selenium webdriver is not able to work on it so I'm stuck. Below is the error:                                                                  

Response code: 500
Response message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be nteracted with Command duration or timeout: 13 milliseconds

Comment: **Do not click** at the element, just use above code snippet to set file path. You should click "Upload" button or use `submit()` method or whatever once done

Comment: I tried this as well but it's not working. Problem over here I think is the class for the id "fileInput" is hidden hence we are getting getting the error **"Response code: 500 Response message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be nteracted with Command"**. Look at the below details when I inspect the element:

<input id="fileInput" class=**"hide"** type="file" multiple="" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().addFiles(this.files)">

Can you get me the work around for this?

Comment: I made the class visible and ran your code it worked but I wanna make the class visible dynamically. Code
  WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("createCaseForm"));
  WebElement element1 = element.findElement(By.id("fileInput"));
  String str = element1.getAttribute("class");
  try
  {
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
   js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('class', 'show');",element1);
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
   
  }
in java makes class visible but not able to write same code in JMeter webdriver. plz get me the equivalent code in JMeter  webdriver

Comment: How to use button navigation in Jmeter webdriver? Can you tell me how could I press Enter button in Jmeter Web Driver Sampler?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111034/sendkeyskeys-tab-not-working-in-jmeter-webdriver-sampler/

Comment: can we perform drag and drop using co-ordinates in Jmeter Selenium webdriver? If yes please get me sample code.

Comment: it is out of scope for this question, create another instead of asking different things via comments